# Expected unqualified-id :4. How to fix it?

Tags: c++, cppunit

```
#define SUM(__FIRST_NUM, __SECOND_NUM) __SUM_
template <class __TYPE_>
__TYPE_ __SUM_(__TYPE_ &__FIRST_NUM, __TYPE_ &__SECOND_NUM)
    return __FIRST_NUM + __SECOND_NUM;      //<- error is here
```

Comment: Start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Then, think about what other context info one needs to understand your question. The above doesn't make it clear what your question is. If in doubt, extract a [mcve] and include that and the full verbatim output it produces in your question.

Comment: Please add your code which calls `__SUM_` function

Comment: You appear to be missing `{ }` in your function. This looks vaguely like python to me right now. C++ uses `{ }` for scope, indentation has no effect.

Comment: Identifiers beginning with double _ are reserved for compiler to use. Your code isn't portable either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.